# How to use an API for downloading information from the Earth Explorer?

Tags: python, post, python-requests

I am trying to understand a little better the API world, I'm trying to download information from the Earth Explorer API and the first thing I am supposed to do is to login. For this i wrote the following:

```
import requests

import requests
usuario = 'xxxxx'
clave = 'xxxxxxxx'

input_data= {"username":usuario,"password":clave,"catalogId":"EE"}
test=requests.post('https://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/inventory/json/v/1.4.1/login',data=input_data)

print(test.text)
print(test.status_code)
```

but this error appears:

```
{"errorCode":"INPUT_FORMAT","error":"A required field 'username' was not found in the request object",
"data":null,"api_version":"1.4.1","access_level":"guest","catalog_id":"default","executionTime":0.10880804061889648}
200
```

According to this I haven't submitted the username but I just did, didn't I, in the `data=input_data`?

Comment: I can help with this but I do not have access to the API documentation as it requires an account.

Comment: Since that's the case for everyone, I would recommend you use google earth engine instead. see [here](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/getstarted)

Comment: Thank you so much to everyone but i actually got a result by installing the ugsc api.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Thank you so much to everyone but i actually got a result by installing the ugsc api.